# MySql where clause fails search

Tags: mysql

On my MySql Workbench, I'm doing a simple search query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test.table 
WHERE originalFilePath = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\documentScanning\output\REQMAN/2018-09-06_10.03.53/TS18-6289.pdf';

SELECT * 
FROM test.table 
WHERE originalFilePath like '%C:\inetpub\wwwroot\documentScanning\output\REQMAN/2018-09-06_10.03.53/TS18-6289.pdf%';

SELECT * 
FROM test.table 
WHERE originalFilePath like '% C:\inetpub\wwwroot\documentScanning\output\REQMAN/2018-09-06_10.03.53/TS18-6289.pdf %';
```

But every query is always empty. From further testing, it appears that the query does not like the 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\documentScanning\output\' for some reason, which is odd, the search value is a direct copy and pastes from the table itself. I've gotten this query to work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test.table 
WHERE originalFilePath like '%\REQMAN/2018-09-06_10.03.53/TS18-6289.pdf';
```

However, this query will be used in a script that runs every 2 minutes and the database is incredibly large so I would prefer not to use the query above but rather a direct search (equals to) since I was told that using a wildcard search could slow things down. Is there a way to do this? Can someone explain why it doesn't like the **'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\documentScanning\output\'** in the search?

Comment: The issue with using a wildcard search is you may not be able to use any indices on the field, when you have a wildcard at the beginning. `LIKE 'A%` can make use of an index, but `LIKE '%A'` can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to double \ in =

You have to quadruple \\ in like

```
SELECT * 
FROM test.table 
WHERE originalFilePath = 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\documentScanning\\output\\REQMAN/2018-09-06_10.03.53/TS18-6289.pdf';

SELECT * 
FROM test.table 
WHERE originalFilePath like '%C:\\\\inetpub\\\\wwwroot\\\\documentScanning\\\\output\\\\REQMAN/2018-09-06_10.03.53/TS18-6289.pdf%';

SELECT * 
FROM test.table 
WHERE originalFilePath like '% C:\\\\inetpub\\\\wwwroot\\\\documentScanning\\\\output\\\\REQMAN/2018-09-06_10.03.53/TS18-6289.pdf %';
```